# How to setup categories model efficiently in python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am setting up a model in Django. There is a field named category which I made a foreign field (because it would contain a lot of categories that will be added through the model).

I want to be able to add more than one category per profile created by the user or in the admin, but I am only able to add one category per profile created.

Please how can I solve this problem, I have no idea how to approach this.

So far, the code below shows how far I have been able to do so far, and the picture to my admin:

[image]

```
from django.conf import settings

from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    bio                     = models.TextField(blank=False)
    personal_website_url    = models.URLField(blank=True)
    personal_website_name   = models.URLField(blank=True)

    general_category        = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.bio or ""
```

How can I add multiple categories per profile? because I am only able to add one category per profile in the Django model.

Comment: Surely you want a ManyToManyField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only save a single object to `ForeignKey` field. if you want to add multiple categories to a single profile use a many-to-many field.

```
   general_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: thanks, so much for your answer, it really did the trick for me. I appreciate a lot